# Create Constants Arraylist return empty

Tags: java, android, arraylist, constants

I would like to create a constant ArrayList but I keep return with empty result.

Please comment is this the right way of declaring a Static Final ArrayList?

```
public final class Constants {
    public static ArrayList<String[]> points = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    {
        points.add( new String[] {"A","5.42420782","100.2680779" } );
        points.add( new String[] {"B","5.42253496","100.26634007" } );
        points.add( new String[] {"C","5.4196543","100.2645124" } );
        points.add( new String[] {"D", "5.41808928","100.26244618" } );
    }

    public static final List<ArrayList<String[]>> fix_points = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(points));
}
```

Trying to return with loop.

```
for(ArrayList<String[]> item : Constants.fix_points) {
   System.out.println(item);
}
```

Print show empty [].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand the  difference between initilization block and static block.

```
{
        points.add( new String[] {"A","5.42420782","100.2680779" } );
        points.add( new String[] {"B","5.42253496","100.26634007" } );
        points.add( new String[] {"C","5.4196543","100.2645124" } );
        points.add( new String[] {"D", "5.41808928","100.26244618" } );
    }
```

That calls when you create an instance of Constants.

Where

```
static {
        points.add( new String[] {"A","5.42420782","100.2680779" } );
        points.add( new String[] {"B","5.42253496","100.26634007" } );
        points.add( new String[] {"C","5.4196543","100.2645124" } );
        points.add( new String[] {"D", "5.41808928","100.26244618" } );
    }
```

calls when the class loads.

You need the later block which is static block.

Answer (score 1):

Replace below line

```
List<ArrayList<String[]>> fix_points = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(points));
```

with `final List<String[]> fix_points = Collections.unmodifiableList(points);`

```
 final List<String[]> fix_points = Collections.unmodifiableList(points);
    for(String[] item : fix_points) {
        for(int i=0;i<item.length;i++)
            System.out.println(item[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need a `List<ArrayList<String[]>>`, but the produced output should be something like (`String[].toString()`)

```
[[Ljava.lang.String;@29ce4d9c, [Ljava.lang.String;@b24c3a5, [Ljava.lang.String;@28e1c37a, [Ljava.lang.String;@1c0b972b]
```

you can print the exact content with

```
for(ArrayList<String[]> item : Constants.fix_points) {
     for (String[] i : item) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), " " + i[0]+ " " +  i [1]);
     }
}
```